# How to close current foreground activity from non activity class

Tags: java, android

I start activity B from activity A.

A call-back method in a non activity class is invoked indicating that I should close Activity B.

How can I close activity B from the non activity class?

Please keep in mind that activity B is not always the same activity, but A is. For example, in my case A is the `MainActivity` and B is any number of other activities which I can launch from `MainActivity`.

TLDR; How do I close the current foreground activity from a non activity class.

Comment: you have to close  Activity B from B. if i under stand you as well .

Comment: Oh, duh. That makes sense.

Comment: it will if you provide more info.

Comment: How do I get a reference to the activity I want to close without setting a static reference?

Comment: You can pass the activity B instance to the non activity class as an argument and then call `finish()` on that instance. Although I don't think that's recomended

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Why don't you think it's recommended? Aren't we passing context object all the time? What wrong with passing an activity?

Comment: Because there's often little  reason to close an Activity manually where the OS handles it. A Context on the other hand is not bound to a lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

you should use broadcast.

you can use a `SuperActivity`,and  other activities extend from `SuperActivity`

register the broadcast in the `SuperActivity`,

```
if(intent.getAction.equals(your custom action))(
    finish();
)
```

and    B Activity extends SuperActivity

pass the `Context` to the non activity class as an argument, at the end of this method,use  `Context` to send broadcast.

don't forget the broadcast should be unregistered when the `B Activity` is `finish`

Answer (score 0):

**Avoiding passing Activity Object to non Activity Class**

you can use listener for this and only pass the listener object ... create

your custom listener and your non Activity class take this listener as a

parameter and then you make a superB activity for all your B Activities

that you want to finish and then your superB implement this listener and

all B Activityes override this listener method.

**Example:**

this is your custom listener

```
public interface CustomLisnter {
    void finishBActivity();
}
```

at your superB Activity you implement this listener

```
public abstract SuperBActivity implements CustomLisnter{
}
```

then at your B Activity extends SuperBActivity and override finishBActivity() method.

```
public BActivity extends SuperBActivity{

//when ever in your code you call non Activity Class that has the callback
// pass this activity in its constrictor like this
SomeClassToFinishActivity mClass = new SomeClassToFinishActivity(this);

   @override
   public finishBActivity(){
     //here you can finish activity
      finish();
   }
}
```

at your non Activity class that responsible for finish current BActivity
pass this listener to it.

```
public SomeClassToFinishActivity {
   private CustomLisnter mListener;
   public SomeClassToFinishActivity(CustomLisnter listener){
      this.mListener = listener;
   }
}
```

and in your callback that should finish the activity call this

```
private void yourCallBackMethodToFinishActivity(){
   mListener.finishBActivity();
}
```

i hope that helps you ..  let me know if you have a question.